# Read a csv file into a list and finding max of each column as well as subtracting each value from its corresponding column max value

Tags: python

The biggest restriction is I cannot import any package other than os. So I have a CSV file(attached a picture of my sample data here [image]) which I read into a list using the below lines of code:

```
with open(input_filename,"r") as infile:
   next(infile)    
   for line in infile:
      line = line.strip()
      my_list.append(line.split(','))
```

So my_list looks like this:

```
my_list = [['A', '0.05', '5.62','-1.65', '0.58'], ['B', '0.03', '6.18','-8.56', '5.26'], ['C', '3.26', '5.78','-2.67', '10.25'], ['D', '0.36', '1.25','-1.78', '']]
```

I need to ignore first 2 columns and find the max of each column. Also I need to subtract Max_value for each value in a row with corresponding max from its column.

So fat I have managed to read the list column wise using the code below:

```
 for k in range(2,len(my_list[0][:])):        
        for j in my_list:      
            col_list.append(j[k])
```

The problem is I get a single list with all column-wise elements. I'm not sure how can I separate them as values from a column, compute the max and then take each element and subtract it from the max value.

The col_list looks like this:
['5.62','6.18','5.78','1.25','-1.65','-8.56','-2.67','-1.78','0.58','5.26','10.25','']

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filename)

for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col] - df[col].max
```

if you can't use pandas, something like this would work. Note that you have an empty cell that I interpreted as 0.

```
for i in my_list:
    tmp = [float(j) if j != "" else 0 for j in i[2:]]
    i[2:] = [ z - max(tmp) for z in tmp ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I cannot use Pandas package. I have updated my post.

Comment: Added a solution that doesn't require any other libraries

Comment: Thanks for your solution, however this calculates the max of each row. I need the max of each column.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the job, no libraries used at all. It is not exactly elegant, but it seems to get the job done with your test cases.

```
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    max_values = [-999,-999,-999]
    for line in f:
            data = line.split(',')
            if (max_values[0] < float(data[2].strip().replace("'",""))):
                max_values[0] = float(data[2].strip().replace("'",""))

            if (max_values[1] < float(data[3].strip().replace("'",""))):
                max_values[1] = float(data[3].strip().replace("'",""))

            if (max_values[2] < float(data[4].strip().replace("'",""))):
                max_values[2] = float(data[4].strip().replace("'",""))

print(max_values)
```

Presumably you can handle the extra part about subtracting max value? I am not totally sure what you mean by that.